# stream was reset: null

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit2, android-proguard

I had a strange bug which was hard to find :-(

In my Android app I use [Retrofit2](https://github.com/square/retrofit) with [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) do access an api. I also use `proguard-android-optimize.txt` to make my app clean and small. And in my `proguard-rules.pro` I have:

```
-assumenosideeffects class timber.log.Timber { *; }
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

With this combination I get this error `stream was reset: null` when I try to access the api.

To fix it I have to remove this `assumenosideeffects` lines from my proguard config. But why? Has anyone an idea why I get this network problem when proguard removes logging methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard `*` matches all methods, including methods in super classes, like `Object#wait()`. You don't really want to remove those invocations, so you should explicitly list the methods for which you want to remove the invocations:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

ProGuard already prints out a warning if you specify the wildcard.